# Beautifulsoup scraper for sport events

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a simple scraper that parses HTML using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and collects the data (schedule of sports events), then clubs them together in a list of dicts.

The code works just fine, but the way I process the data is pretty horrible IMO. I use an `if...else` to parse the data selectively, because the output of the dicts are alternative, that is `{venue, result (if available)}`, and time of match, and team information.

So basically, is there a better, more reliable way to parse the data?

```
import requests
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
class cricket(object):

    def getMatches(self, url):
        """ Scrape the given url for match schedule """

        headers = {'Accept':'text/css,*/*;q=0.1',
        'Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'}

        page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        page_content = page.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content)

        result = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'bElementBox'})
        tags = result.findChildren('tr')

        match_type_list = ['TEST', 'ODI', 'T20'] 
        match_info = []

        for elem in range(1,len(tags)):
            dict_ = {}
            x = tags[elem].getText()
            x = x.replace(r'&nbsp;', '')

            if 'Venue' in x:
                for a in match_type_list:
                    if a in x:
                        match_type = a

                x = x.replace('Venue', '')
                if 'Result' in x:
                    x = x.replace('Result', '')
                    x = x.split(': ')
                    # print x
                    venue = x[1]
                    result = x[2]
                    dict_.update({'venue':venue,'result':result,
                        'match_type':match_type})
                else:
                    x = x.split(': ')
                    venue = x[1]
                    dict_.update({'venue':venue})

            else:
                match = re.search(r'\b[AP]M', x)
                date_time = x[0:match.end()]
                date_time = date_time.replace(',','')[4:]
                teams = x[match.end():].split('vs')
                home_team = teams[0].strip()
                away_team = teams[1].strip()
                # print date_time, home_team, away_team

                time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%b %d %Y %I:%M %p')                
                timings = time_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
                dict_.update({'home_team':home_team,
                    'away_team':away_team,
                    'timings':timings
                })

            match_info.append(dict_)


        # print match_info

        final_list = []     # final list of dicts that we need

        for i in range(0, len(match_info), 2):
            final_list.append(dict(match_info[i].items() +
                match_info[i+1].items()))

        # for i in final_list:
        #     print i
        # print final_list



if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/series/fixtures.php?seriesCode=ENG_WI_2012' # change seriesCode in URL for different series.
    #url = 'http://localhost:6543/lhost/static/icc_cricket.html'
    c = cricket()
    c.getMatches(url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
class cricket(object):
```

Python conventions state that classes should CamelCase.

```
    def getMatches(self, url):
```

Python convention states that methods should be lowercase_with_underscores. Also, there isn't really a reason to have this method in a class anyway. Seems to me that it should be a function.

```
        """ Scrape the given url for match schedule """

        headers = {'Accept':'text/css,*/*;q=0.1',
        'Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'}
```

I'd move this out of the function into a global constant.

```
        page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        page_content = page.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content)
```

I'd combine these three lines

```
soup = BeatifulSoup(request.get(url, headers = headers).content)


        result = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'bElementBox'})
        tags = result.findChildren('tr')
```

I'd avoid non-descriptive names like result. Tags is a bit better, but not by a whole lot. I'd also combine these two lines

```
tags = soup.find('div', attr={'class':'bElementBox'}).findChildren('tr')




        match_type_list = ['TEST', 'ODI', 'T20'] 
        match_info = []

        for elem in range(1,len(tags)):
```

It'd make more sense to process things two rows at a time.

```
            dict_ = {}
```

Useless name alert.

```
            x = tags[elem].getText()
            x = x.replace(r'&nbsp;', '')
```

At this point, you extract the text and throw out the html. But the data is divided in table cells, so why in the world wouldn't you want to take advantage of that? At this point you drop down to trying to extract data straight from the text which much harder then if you can use the tags as hints.

```
            if 'Venue' in x:
                for a in match_type_list:
                    if a in x:
                        match_type = a

                x = x.replace('Venue', '')
                if 'Result' in x:
                    x = x.replace('Result', '')
                    x = x.split(': ')
                    # print x
                    venue = x[1]
                    result = x[2]
```

All this work to extract data from the string is something you really should use a regular expression for. This is exactly the kind of situation it excells at.

```
                    dict_.update({'venue':venue,'result':result,
                        'match_type':match_type})
```

Its not clear why you would choose to update rather then simply assign. There is no way that any other line of code in this loop can assign to it.

```
                else:
                    x = x.split(': ')
                    venue = x[1]
                    dict_.update({'venue':venue})

            else:
                match = re.search(r'\b[AP]M', x)
                date_time = x[0:match.end()]
                date_time = date_time.replace(',','')[4:]
                teams = x[match.end():].split('vs')
                home_team = teams[0].strip()
                away_team = teams[1].strip()

                # print date_time, home_team, away_team

                time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
```

Organization seems a little suspect. You jump from working on the date, over to the teams, and then back to the date. I'd stick with date until it was finished. You also spend a bunch of lines massaging the date. However, strptime lets you specify any format you want, so you should just be able to have it parse the data

```
                timings = time_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
```

If I'm parsing, I wouldn't convert the time back into a date in another object. I'd keep it as a date object.

```
                dict_.update({'home_team':home_team,
                    'away_team':away_team,
                    'timings':timings
                })

            match_info.append(dict_)


        # print match_info

        final_list = []     # final list of dicts that we need

        for i in range(0, len(match_info), 2):
            final_list.append(dict(match_info[i].items() +
                match_info[i+1].items()))
```

I'd do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(match_info), 2):
    left, right = match_info[i:i+2]
    final_list.append( dict(left.items() + right.items() )
```

I think it makes things a bit clearer.

```
        # for i in final_list:
        #     print i
        # print final_list
```

this function probably needs to return that list or something.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/series/fixtures.php?seriesCode=ENG_WI_2012' # change seriesCode in URL for different series.
    #url = 'http://localhost:6543/lhost/static/icc_cricket.html'
    c = cricket()
    c.getMatches(url)
```

Good

Here is my reworking of your code:

```
def get_cricket_matches(content):
    """ Scrape the given content for match schedule """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    all_rows = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'bElementBox'}).findChildren('tr')

    match_info = []

    for index in range(1, len(all_rows), 2):
        rows = [row.findChildren('td') for row in all_rows[index:index+2]]

        data = {
            'match_type' : rows[1][0].findChildren('b')[1].getText(),
            'home_team': rows[0][2].getText(),
            'away_team' : rows[0][5].getText(),
            'match_time' : datetime.strptime(rows[0][0].getText(), '%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p'),
        }
        for line in rows[1][1].findAll('b'):
            content = str(line.nextSibling)[1:]
            if line.getText() == 'Venue':
                data['venue'] = content
            else:
                data['result'] = content

        match_info.append(data)

    return match_info
```

> Personally, I don't like dependencies (in this case requests and
>   BeautifulSoup). Why just not to use the standard modules?

Here I have to strongly disagree with @cat_baxter. Dependencies are the best part of python. That is, the availability and ease of installing all these different libraries to make it easier to write code is a great asset of Python. You should never be worried about taking on dependencies that are easy to install if it helps.

Having said that, you don't get a whole lot out of the `requests` module. So an argument can be made that this code would be better off using urllib.

But then the question is whether its a good idea to parse HTML with regex. With scraping you can get away with using a regex because regardless of the technique you use, changes to the page's structure will probably break it. The question at that point is which version has simpler and easier to write code.

Compare:

```
re.match('<div class="bElementBox">.+<tbody>(.+).+</tbody>.+</div>', page).group(1)
```

and

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'bElementBox'})
```

The HTML parser method takes advantage of knowing the structure of html to make it fairly easy to find the element. Is the regex entirely correctly? (Technically no, because simply regex can't parse HTML correctly, but is it good enough for job? I assume so, but I have more confidence in the HTML parser.)

```
columns = re.compile('<td.*?>(.*?)</td>', re.DOTALL | re.M).findall(table)
```

An equivalent would be

```
columns = table.findall('td')
```

Again, HTML parser wins hands down.

```
        'home_team' : columns[index + 2],
```

VS:

```
        'home_team': rows[0][2].getText(),
```

The difference between `rows[0][2]` and `columns[index + 2]` is the fact that I choose to structure the parser after the rows, whereas `cat_baxter` decided to throw away the rows and look just at the columns. Either approach can be done either way, so that's incidental to this question. But here the HTML parser method is slightly more complicated because it has to use `.getText()`

```
        'venue'     : re.match("<b>Venue</b>: ([\s,\w\']+)", columns[index + 7]).group(1), 

m = re.match('.+Result</b>:([\w, ]+)', columns[index + 7]) 
if m: 
   row['result'] = m.group(1)
```

Vs

```
    for line in rows[1][1].findAll('b'):
        content = str(line.nextSibling)[1:]
        if line.getText() == 'Venue':
            data['venue'] = content
        else:
            data['result'] = content
```

I think this one is hard to call. I think my lines of code have less going on in them, but I think it might be somewhat more obvious what is happening in the regular expression.

My ending conclusion is that HTML parsers for scraping is often much nicer then using a regex, and sometimes a little worse. On the balance, I think its a way better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like dependencies (in this case requests and BeautifulSoup). Why just not to use the standard modules?

```
import urllib, re

URL = 'http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/series/fixtures.php?seriesCode=ENG_WI_2012'
page = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()

# just for the testing - the url above is unavailable, grab it from google cache and write to the page.txt
#page = open("page.txt").read() 

# find the table
table = re.match('<div class="bElementBox">.+<tbody>(.+).+</tbody>.+</div>', page).group(1)

# extract all columns
columns = re.compile('<td.*?>(.*?)</td>', re.DOTALL | re.M).findall(table)
result = []

# process them by 8
for index in range(0, len(columns), 8):
    row = {
            'home_team' : columns[index + 2], 
            'away_team' : columns[index + 5], 
            'match_type': re.match('.+<b>([A-Z,0-9]+)</b>',columns[index + 6]).group(1), 
            'venue'     : re.match("<b>Venue</b>: ([\s,\w\']+)", columns[index + 7]).group(1), 
            'timings'   : columns[index], 
          }
    m = re.match('.+Result</b>:([\w, ]+)', columns[index + 7]) 
    if m: 
       row['result'] = m.group(1)
    result.append(row)

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about going back and using urllib, but won't you agree that parsing raw HTML can be a too much with just regex?

Comment: No, you can't parse HTML with regex. Really. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/282912

Comment: It's possible and it's easy :)

Comment: What do you have against using libraries? From a [recent question of mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48258/well-be-counting-stars) I was told to avoid using `urllib`. There's an item in *Effective Java* stating that you should know and use the libraries, I'm sure this applies to Python as well.